# React object, display key names

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-read-json-jw6xeo)

It's a simple React TypeScript app where I am displaying an object

The object is like

```
{
    "default": {
        "ProductSize": {
            "min": 32
        },
        "ProductHeight": {
            "min": 15
        },
        "ProductWeight": 50
    },
    "ProductOne": {
        "ProductSize": {
            "min": 20,
            "max": 15
            },
        "ProductHeight": {
            "min": 50,
            "max": 87
        },
        "ProductSpacing": 90,
        "ProductWeight": 100
      },    
    "ProductTwo": {
        "ProductSize": {
            "min": 43,
            "max": 67
            },
        "ProductHeight": {
            "min": 12,
            "max": 78
        },
        "ProductSpacing": 34,
        "ProductWeight": 56
      }
  
}
```

I can pull out parts of the jsons like

```
<ul>
    {Object.keys(ProductData).map(key => (
        <li key={key}>{ProductData[key].ProductSize.min}</li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

but how can I get the key name for each block

So I want to list

```
default
ProductOne
ProductTwo
ProductThree
```

I have tried

```
<li key={key}>{ProductData[key].key}</li>
```

but I get an empty list item

Comment: isn't the value of `key` what you are looking for? So just `<li key={key}>{key}</li>`

Comment: JSON is a text format; you have an object, not a "json object".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer

You already have keys array through `Object.keys(ProductData)`

So it will be simple

```
<ul>
    {Object.keys(ProductData).map(key => (
        <li key={key}>{key}</li>
    ))}
</ul>
```

#### Theory

`Object.keys(obj)` returns array of `obj` keys, [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```
const obj = {
  foo: 12
  bar: 'bar'
}

// will return ['foo', 'bar']
const keys = Object.keys(obj);

// will return <li key="foo"}>foo</li><li key="bar">bar</li>
const items = keys.map((key) => <li key={key}>{key}</li>)
```

If you will need a key and a value together [see Object.entries() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```
// will return [['foo', 12], ['bar', 'bar']]
const entries = Object.entries(obj);

// will return <li key="foo"}>foo: 12</li><li key="bar">bar: bar</li>
const items = entries.map(([key, value]) => <li key={key}>{key}: {value}</li>);
```

For [key, value] syntax [see destructuring docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)